# Second derivate to prove value of a function

Tags: calculus

If I want to know if a function, using real
numbers, will always comply with $|g'(x)|<1$ I have to use the second derivative?.

The function is defined in an interval $[a,b]$, why do I have to use the second derivative to prove that?
Thanks, my mother tongue is not English Sorry.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but if all you know about $g$ is that $g$ is defined on some interval $[a,b]$ and $|g'(x)| < 1$ (I'm assuming for all $x \in [a,b]$) then you can't uniquely determine $g$.  More info is needed.  For example, $f(x)=2/x$ on $[4,7]$ and $h(x) = \ln x$ on $[10,11]$ are two functions that satisfy those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the second derivative can give you information about the maximum and the minimum.
That way you can check if the absolute value is always less than 1.

EDIT: I'm not sure if this is what you meant